# os.getcwd() for a different drive in Windows

Tags: python

According to http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html

> "On Windows, there is a current directory for each drive"

This is giving me some trouble when I use `os.getcwd()` on Windows.

I am using Python 2.7 on my C drive to call a script located on the shared network drive F:. Yet, `os.getcwd()` from within this script is returning a directory on my C drive.

Is there anything I can do to get the working directory for my F drive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, it depends:

If Python is started directly (not going through cmd.exe), then yes, you only have the one current directory (it's like always specifying cd /d ...):

```
--> import os
--> os.getcwd()
'c:\\source\\dbf-dev'
--> os.chdir('z:')
--> os.getcwd()
'Z:\\'
--> os.chdir('c:')    # assumes root directory
--> os.getcwd()
'C:\\'
```

But, if you start Python from cmd.exe, you get the historical perspective:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'Z:\\perm-c'
>>> os.chdir('c:')    # does not assume root directory
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Source\\Path'
>>> os.chdir('d:')
>>> os.getcwd()
'D:\\'
>>> os.chdir('l:')
>>> os.getcwd()
'L:\\'
>>> os.chdir('l:\\letter')
>>> os.getcwd()
'l:\\letter'
>>> os.chdir('z:')
>>> os.getcwd()
'Z:\\perm-c'
>>> os.chdir('l:\\')
>>> os.getcwd()
'l:\\'
```

Undoubtedly this is an artifact of cmd.exe doing its thing behind the scenes.

To answer your original question, though -- the only way to find out the current directory on drive f: is

- 1) to have started Python from cmd.exe
- 2) os.chdir() to 'f:'
- 3) os.getcwd()
- 4) os.chdir() back (if desired)

Answer (score 2):

This is factually incorrect. Each process has a single working directory. There is no separate working directory for different drives.

For a historical perspective, have a read of this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/11/10073890.aspx) by Raymond Chen.

Comment: Any idea why os.getcwd() might be returning something on the C drive? I am using Windows XP.

Comment: that will be because the working directory is on C when you ask

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the section you are reading that from is worded poorly. There is only one current working directory for your python session, and you get it from `os.getcwd()`. You can use `os.chdir(r'F:\')` to change directories to your F drive.

The part that that quote is referencing is relating to the `os.path.join` method. It means that passing a first argument of `'C:'` instead of `r'C:\'`, you will get the incorrect path (namely `C:path` instead of `C:\\path`).

Comment: Looking back, maybe this isn't the correct answer... I'm not sure of a way to see what is considered the cwd of the other drive.

Comment: FYI, there's an active discussion [about this](http://bugs.python.org/issue1669539) in the Python bug tracker.