# Why doesn't 'C:' mean what I think it means?

Tags: python, windows, path, directory, getcwd

On Windows 7 I fire up my IDLE Python 2.7.5 Shell:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Python27'
>>> os.path.relpath('C:\\')
'..'
>>> os.path.relpath('C:')
'.'
>>> os.chdir('C:')
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Python27'
```

What is going on, and why does it have to be this complicated?

Comment: This all makes sense. `C:` without a path designation represents the current directory on drive `C:`. So the relative path is `.` since you are on drive `C:` And since you are at `C:\\Python27`, then the relative path to `C:\\` is `..`.

Comment: That goes back to DOS days, where "cd X:" would take you to the last directory you were in on X:, not necessarily the root directory of X:.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows the behaviour can be a bit strange - it behaves differently if you start Python from cmd.exe or if you start it directly (not going through cmd.exe). As has been pointed out the correct command is `os.chdir('c:\\')`. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614323/os-getcwd-for-a-different-drive-in-windows) provides more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You are not trying to change to actual folder, but to "c:", proper command will be

```
import os 
os.chdir('c:\\')
```

And it will work just fine. The reason for double backslash is to escape the backslash (which works as escape character).

Comment: Ok, but why is it set up this way? To me 'c:' should mean the root folder 'c:\'. Is there a good reason for 'c:' to still 'be' in a particular folder. Do all drives have a 'cwd' at all times?

Comment: @Scruffy that sounds like a fabulous thing for you to test out (and it is easy, altogether with being a fun exercise, i promise!). As for why, it is a leftover that windows inherited from very old times.

Comment: @Scruffy As I explain in my answer, this depends on how you run Python.

Comment: @Scruffy: "To me 'c:' should mean the root folder 'c:\'." -- but you didn't invent DOS, so it's not your call ;-) When Python runs on Windows it makes sure that paths beginning with "C:" mean the same thing in Python as they do to Windows.

Comment: Yes, all drives have a current directory at all times.  (Well, to all effects and purposes.)  This is remarkably useful at the command line.